# JSON field saves as longtext datatype

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.3

I'm trying to create JSON column in 10.3.16-MariaDB but every time I save the configuration in PHPMyAdmin, the column saves as longtext datatype.

No errors shown :|

Where could be the problem?

System specs: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.7 and PHPMyAdmin 4.9.0.1 versions

Comment: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.7 and PHPMyAdmin 4.9.0.1 versions

Comment: Please edit the question and put those extra details in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MariaDB does not have a datatype of `JSON`.  Instead it gives you `LONGTEXT`.

Be aware that there are a lot of differences between MySQL and MariaDB in the area of JSON.  Furthermore, different versions of each have different levels of functions, etc.